# Python Pandas check dataframe groupby, how many people have the same book combinations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

So I have a list of people, each of them are given more than 2 books, 4 books are possible.
I want to do a groupby and check frequency of  combination of book received
such as [ID, books]
such ID: 1, he has Books: A, B
I want to know how many people had received book combination of A and B.

Technically if someone has books A,B,C; he will have combination of (A,B),(A,C),(B,C),(A,B,C).

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   'disease': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']})[enter image description here][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A26La.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example of dataset? Ensure you read [how to provide reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) first

Comment: Sorry this was my first time. 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'disease': [a, b, b, c, a, b, c]})

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` operations.

Identify users with a given target combination:

```
target = {'a', 'b'}
df.groupby('user')['disease'].agg(lambda x: target.issubset(x))
```

Output:

```
user
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: disease, dtype: bool
```

Count the number of users that match the target:

```
target = {'a', 'b'}
df.groupby('user')['disease'].agg(lambda x: target.issubset(x)).sum()
```

Output: `2`

Comment: Thank you mozway, but I was thinking not use a given target combination. Becuase there could be lots of combinations, I have more than 20 differents book types. That is why I am stuck for a long time.

Comment: @XinfaP. Thus the importance of clearly defining your expected output. We cannot invent the logic for you. For 20 types, you have more than 1 million possible combinations (see [power set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)), is this something you want to work with?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. I think I would want to create a new column if a new combination shows up. for example, if there is a person with combination of A and B, the new column [A, B] will be created, and flaged 1 for this person. 
If a combination column has been created before, the next person will just flag 1 on that existing combination column.  
Again I apologize for the mistake, will improve next time!

Comment: Well you can still update your question. Think about it carefully, come up with a clear minimal example, edit your question to add it and I'll receive a notification.

Comment: I updated a photo of like my current most clear ideal example, because the format structure in text looks different as I typed in words.